Question regarding Fitch's paradox of knowability
Section 2 of Fitch's paradox of knowability states the following.
Let $K$ be the epistemic operator 'it is known by someone at some time that.’ Let $\diamond$ be the modal operator ‘it is possible that’. Suppose the knowability principle (KP)—that all truths are knowable by somebody at some time:
$$\text{(KP)} \qquad\qquad \forall p(p\rightarrow \diamond Kp).$$
And suppose that collectively we are non-omniscient, that there is an unknown truth:
$$\text{(NonO)}\qquad\qquad \exists (p\wedge\neg Kp).$$
Here is my question.
It seems to me (KP) and (NonO) contradict each other unless $\diamond$ makes a big difference. What exactly is that difference and how is "it is possible" defined?

They’re mutually consistent. Take a pair of possible worlds where one is accessible to the other. Take only one $p$ such that $p$ is false at the world that can access the other world, and known at the accessible world. In this case, $p$ is false, but it is possible to know it, since there is a world where it is true and knowable.

@PW_246: How do you define "worlds" and "accessible"?

A world is a point where formulas take a truth value. The accessibility relation is a binary relation on worlds such that whenever $\Diamond A$ is true at a world $w$, there is a world $v$ accessible from $w$ where $A$ is true. Dually, $\Box A$ is true at $w$ iff $A$ is true at all accessible worlds. The accessibility relation is defined further by the Kripke frames that a certain accessibility relation. For example, $\Box P \to P$ is the defining formula for reflexive frames, i.e. frames in which every world is accessible to itself.

PW_246 should have started by saying: "these are terms used in what are called the Kripke semantics for modal logic, which allow you to give precise meanings to modal operators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics."

It should be noted upfront that there is no genuine paradox in Frederic Fitch's argument (which had been suggested by Alonzo Church), whether formally or informally. It might be said to be a slingshot argument (so-called because of its simplicity in a complicated situation, alluding to biblical David's taking Goliath down by a sling) that poses a puzzling conundrum for a number of well-wrought theories.
The two principles, knowability and non-omniscience, actually describe a setting quite familiar to us from mathematics: We prove that there exists at least one with a particular property among a set of objects, however, we do not know which (see the Wikipedia article on constructive proof to have a clearer view of this issue).
Likewise, we may read the two principles as:
All true propositions are eligible (that is the point that possibility operator enters) for our knowledge (i.e., by being true), however, since our overall epistemic competence is bounded, at least one of them will remain unbeknownst to us, but we cannot have an idea about which.
Naturally, such a viewpoint requires classical logic, as opposed to, specifically, intuitionistic logic. That is why Timothy Williamson contends that the significance of intuitionistic logic has been corroborated by the Church-Fitch argument, rather than beset by it (see his 1982 paper "Intuitionism Disproved?").
The standard method to formalise intensional notions like possibility and necessity is the possible worlds semantics introduced by Saul Kripke. We cannot go into its details here; I recommend Open Logic Project's freely available book Boxes and Diamonds for its clarity and thoroughness on this subject. See SoEP article "Epistemic Logic" by Rasmus Rendsviget et al. for its application in epistemic logic. Finally, one may wish to go through Takashi Yagisawa's SEoP article "Possible Objects" for a broader conceptual account of possibility.
